# Assigning variable value to Spark Streaming Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have to count the number of tuples in a DStream and, depending on the value, I have to modify the value of a boolean variable. 
Unfortunately it seems that what I've done is not assigning the new value.
This is the code:

```
val teon = false

s1.foreachRDD( rdd => {
System.out.println("# events = " + rdd.count())
  if (rdd.count().>(1000)) 
    teon.equals(true) 
  else 
    teon.equals(false)
})

if(teon){
 val ton2 = s2.map { x => x.sensor_name }
 ton2.print
}
else {
  val ton3 = s2.map { x => x.stt.spatial.unit }
  ton3.print
}
```

`s1` and `s2`are DStream[Sensor] (Sensor is a custom class).

Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the intention here? What are `s1` and `s2` ? One basic error is that `teon` is a value and not a variable, but changing it to `var` will not achieve the expected result. The approach needs to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues at hand in this code:

The first one is that `teon` is declared as a `val`. It's immutable and, as such, its value will never change during the execution of the program.

The second issue is structural. The transformations declared at the `DStream` level, like :

```
if(teon){
 val ton2 = s2.map { x => x.sensor_name }
 ton2.print
}
```

will be evaluated only once when the program is first loaded and added to the Dstream transformation DAG for execution. Let's remember that the `DStream` programming model is based on transformations that are applied when the `streamingContext` starts. These steps will define a single transformation path based on the initial value of `teon` and that will not change afterward.

As we want to make dynamic choices based on the values *contained* in the stream, we need to take those decisions *within* the context of a `DStream` operation.

Taking that into consideration, the code should look like:

```
var teon = false

s1.foreachRDD{ rdd => 
  val count = rdd.count // compute it only once!
  System.out.println("# events = " + count)
  teon  =  count > 1000 // use the boolean value directly
}

s2.foreachRDD { rdd =>  
  val ton = if (teon) { 
    rdd.map( x => x.sensor_name )
  } else {
    rdd.map( x => x.stt.spatial.unit ) // I'm assuming here that sensor_name and _stt.spatial_unit are the same type.
  }
  ton.take(10).foreach(e => println(e)) // implement DStream.print "by hand"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val teon = false    
...   
...    
...    
if(teon)
```

It doesn't make sense.
**val** means that you can't change value of the variable (It's like **final** in Java). So it always will be false.
If you want to change the value you need to use:

```
 var teon = false
```